# Serialize(TextWriter, Object) vs Serialize(XmlWriter, Object)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

The [XmlSerializer.Serialize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize(v=vs.110).aspx) has overloads that accept `TextWriter` and `XmlWriter`.

My question is what are the practical differences between these two overloads in the follow examples? (`list` is a `List<MyObjectModel>`)

Example 1 (with `TextWriter`):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectModel));

using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savePath))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
}
```

Example 2 (with `XmlWriter`):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectModel));

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(savePath))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
}
```

So far I've noticed that:

1) `TextWriter` seems to automatically perform indenting for you.

2) The default encoding for both is UTF-8.

Comment: `TextWriter` is an abstract class, so I imagine the idea is that you can either use the `XmlWriter.Create` provided or roll with your own implementation of `TextWriter` if you need custom behaviour.

Comment: There are `XmlWriter` subclasses that write to other things that strings or streams.  For instance [`XContainer.CreateWriter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates an `XmlWriter` you can use to serialize directly to a LINQ-to-XML document or element.  Similarly you can use [`XPathNavigator.AppendChild()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163341%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the old `XmlDocument` API.

Comment: @dbc: Thanks. That was helpful in understanding the differences better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the difference in [the source code reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,278):

```
public void Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces) {
    XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter);
    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlWriter.Indentation = 2;
    Serialize(xmlWriter, o, namespaces);
}
```

In short, the `TextWriter` overload uses a `XmlTextWriter` underneath the hood and sets the formatting for you.